# How can I restore the synchronization between the auto-create forms list and the DPR initialization code?

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a D2006 app in which the DPR file has had numerous edits (yes, I know - you shouldn't mess with the DPR file) to accommodate such things as a splash screen, preventing a second instance of the app being started, handling of command line options that need to be processed before any forms are created, etc.

One day, I noticed that the auto-create forms list in the project options is empty - but the DPR file still has the code in there to create some of the forms.

If I try to restore all the forms that should be auto-created from the dialog, it complains `Error - Call to Application->CreateForm is missing or incorrect` and doesn't do anything.

- How can I restore this connection - apart from rebuilding the DPR from scratch?
- is it safe to manually add the `CreateForm` calls?
- are there any documented rules as to what you can do in the DPR file?
- I have a suspicion that try..except and if..else clauses in the DPR upset Delphi.  Will moving as many functions as possible to a separate unit and calling them be helpful?

Comment: I think the code in the .dpr file is a total nightmare because the  IDE makes a mess of it. I'd just make a function named Main and call it from the .dpr begin/end. Then you can gain control.

Comment: OK, say I do that - effectively hiding all of my functionality from the IDE - surely Delphi will still try to add all of the form creation stuff in front of my call to `Main()`?  I'm beginning to wonder if the best way isn't to do as you suggest - put everything in a separate `Main` unit, remove all forms from the auto-create list dialog (and hope Delphi respects my wishes), and explicitly create what I want to be created at startup inside the `Main` unit.

Comment: The solution here is to remove all the auto-creation code, remove the global variables that the IDE creates for each form, and create and destroy your forms as needed.

Comment: One of the lovely things about having version control is that it's easy to revert changes you don't want.  You can never get Delphi to stop modifying the code in the .dpr when you add forms, but like Nick says, you do get to change it all back again, and if you want to go with a completely self-contained memory management system you can.

Comment: @ross Yes, I would do that. And remove all those horrible global variables.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't really seen any documented rules as to what you can do in the DPR file, because I guess there are no strict rules.

The problem begins when you create a "Forms" application. (No problems with console or non-GUI applications I've noticed).
The IDE will automatically change the DPR any time you add a new Form or a DataModule to it, by assuming you want to auto-create them.

This can mess up your DPR, if it has a lot of code/compiler-directives/if-blocks/try-catch blocks etc...

So I'll tell you what *my* rules are, and in a short line: 
**Keep it as simple as you can.**

My DPR contains only a call to some init code and auto creates the main form only:

```
MyAppInit; // in AppInit unit
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
Application.Run;
```

However in the **uses** section I add (or keep what the IDE added) all the forms my application uses (and also application related units) - this is useful when I want to `view->forms` or `view-units`.
In-fact when I add a new form to the application, the first thing I do is go the DPR and remove the line:

```
Application.CreateForm(TMyNewForm, MyNewForm);
```

**NOTE** (EDIT): The IDE can be configured to NOT auto create forms (No `Application.CreateForm` entry will be created in the DPR). In older version of Delphi this option is under: `Tools/Environment Options/Preferences -> Auto create forms`. In newer versions: `Tools/Options/VCL Designer/Module creation options -> Auto create forms & data modules`.

At run-time, I create all my forms dynamically *when I need them*, and destroy them when they no longer needed. DataModules/Splash (etc...) are created on the MainForm.OnCreate event.

This method has worked for *me* nicely for the past few years maintaining a large scale DB application. This will probably not cover *all* cases, but it worked fine for my needs.

---

P.S: *"Is it safe to manually add the CreateForm calls"* - Yes. But think twice if you really *need* them to be auto-create by the application.

Comment: In modern Delphi you don't need to go and remove the CreateForm call, better configure your IDE to not add that line unchecking the option: `Tools/Options/VCL Designer/Module creation options -> Auto create forms & data modules`. ;)

Comment: @jachguate, since which version of Delphi is it available?

Comment: Since a long time (if memory serves me right: somewhere around Delphi 3), but it has moved around in the IDE options a few times.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers, jachguate, Thanks! :) I was not aware of this option. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO You don't really need that AutoCreate forms from Delphi, but maybe in the casual test project.

And the dpr is just another source code file, where you're meant to write code to make things happen (or prevent it to happen), so don't worry if you lost that sincronization, which IMHO is buggy if can't read your pascal code to work properly.

If you still want to create some forms from the DPR, add the Application.CreateForm or TMyForm.Create calls manually to the file, AFAIK there's no rules against doing it that way.

Comment: IDE does not agree with you. It likes to "own" a primary file and will keep rearrange code (or complain when it can not). My suggestion is to not overuse code editor on the project file, doing so might break project options.

Comment: While the rule (don't write your own code into DPR) isn't spelled out anywhere the fact that IDE fu*** it up makes it kind of "de facto rule" anyway... it seems that anything beyond some simple function call is messed up sooner or later and it just isn't worth the pain in the butt.

Comment: NOTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333794/using-conditionals-in-projects-main-unit-ide-destroys-code

Comment: FWIW I never have to remove any CreateForm lines, so I guess there is some option in the IDE to suppress the autocreation of newly added forms.

Comment: @Uli yes, there's an option to disable AutoCreateForms in `Tools/Options/VCL Designer/Module creation options -> Auto create forms & data modules`

Answer (score 1):

Since Delphi owns the .DPR, [I put my startup logic into a separate unit for each project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762194/how-to-prevent-delphi-modifying-its-dpr-project-source-unexpectedly/6767221#6767221).

That works really well, only very few entries need to be in the .DPR.

Since that unit controls the `Application.CreateForm` logic too, the IDE has an empty list for that: I'm fine with that.

The only things left in the .DPR are:

- the big `uses` that indicates which modules are part of your project
- a call to `Main` in the startup logic unit

Comment: +1, however this *question* now appears like a (couple) duplicate(s).

Comment: One of the moderators can probably merge the questions and answers.